# Laravel: Create tables with variable in name

Tags: database, laravel, migration

How can i create and migrate lots of  tables in laravel with a variable in their name?
I need to create a table "`time-{{user_id}}`" every time a new user is added to a table called "`users`".

How can i realize this and how does the `Migrationfile/Controller/whatever` has to look like?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the main reason you want to create multiple tables instead of just storing the data in a single table that has a `user_id` column?

Comment: I have a main table called users, which stores data like names, date of birth etc.
Now i need a table for each user where i can store something like a CV.. Date begin, date end, City etc.

Comment: You need to be adding rows to a table, not adding new tables

Comment: Well.. But than i will have one giant table with all users mixed? So: user_id, begin, end etc.?
Isn't that kind of ugly? It was recommended to me to make one table per user.. But may this was wrong..

Comment: In that case, I would suggest making different tables for the different resources you're going to be storing e.g. `user_csvs`. The for things like `city` (assuming city is where the user lives) you can store in the `users` table.

Comment: http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/

Comment: Well.. A 1:1 relationship doesnt make any sense for me.
Maybe User A had three Stations in his CV.. Lets say school, university and job.. Each one has a date he started, ended the city, where he went to school, university.. and some other columns..
So the suggested 1:1 relationship doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Now i need a table for each user where i can store something like a CV.. Date begin, date end, City etc"

Sounds like you need another table with a 1:1 relationship to the users table

Your new table will look something like

```
tblFurtherUserInfo
FurtherUserInfoId
CV
DateBegin
DateEnd
City
```

You should add a new row to this table and set FurtherUserInfoID to be the same as the userID in your user table. You should do this whenever you add a record to your user table

**EDIT**

Now I know a user can have more than one CV, you need a new table as follows

```
tblCV
CVId
UserId
CV
DateBegin
DateEnd
City
```

This is a 1 user : many CVs relationship

Comment: Okay.. So this would result in one single table with the CVs of all the users mixed, right? And the data can be later connected to the user by comparing FurtherUserInfoId to UserId?

Comment: Well.. A 1:1 relationship doesnt make any sense for me.
Maybe User A had three Stations in his CV.. Lets say school, university and job.. Each one has a date he started, ended the city, where he went to school, university.. and some other columns..
So the suggested 1:1 relationship doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It wasn't stated in the question that the user could have more thane one CV, I will update the answer but it will be like what Ross Wilson suggested above in that case

Comment: so a simple 1:n Relationship?
I am sorry, assumed it is clear you can have more than one station in your CV.